# Issue getting COUNT to return NULL values as 0

Tags: mysql, ms-access, count, null

I need a Count to return a 0 when it finds nothing to feed into a report.

I found a resource that said I need to use MS Access' NZ function but it doesn't seem to work. It's all one table so the join isn't the issue.

```
SELECT tbl_Supporting.Ref, tbl_Supporting.Application, tbl_Supporting.Level, NZ(Count(tbl_Supporting.Level),0) AS CountOfLevel34
FROM tbl_Supporting
GROUP BY tbl_Supporting.Ref, tbl_Supporting.Application, tbl_Supporting.Level
WHERE (((tbl_Supporting.Level)=3)) OR (((tbl_Supporting.Level)=4));
```

seems to return the exact same thing as

```
SELECT tbl_Supporting.Ref, tbl_Supporting.Application, tbl_Supporting.Level, Count(tbl_Supporting.Level AS CountOfLevel34
FROM tbl_Supporting
GROUP BY tbl_Supporting.Ref, tbl_Supporting.Application, tbl_Supporting.Level
WHERE (((tbl_Supporting.Level)=3)) OR (((tbl_Supporting.Level)=4));
```

Could anyone advise me why this might be? There are definitely NULL values it should be returning.

Answer (score 0):

Use IFNULL function. i.e. IFNULL(count(field), 0)

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull

EDIT: If the issue is in MS Access, then move the NZ function to be in the count params:

count(nz(tbl_Supporting.Level),0)

Answer (score 0):

As you have:

```
WHERE tbl_Supporting.Level=3
```

you will not retrieve, not to say count, any records where Level is Null.

So Nz can't add anything here:

```
NZ(Count(tbl_Supporting.Level),0)
```

You will have to modify your criteria.

OK, then you may have to Sum instead of Count:

```
SELECT tbl_Supporting.Ref, tbl_Supporting.Application, tbl_Supporting.Level, Sum(Int(tbl_Supporting.Level / 3)) AS CountOfLevel34
FROM tbl_Supporting
GROUP BY tbl_Supporting.Ref, tbl_Supporting.Application, tbl_Supporting.Level
WHERE (((tbl_Supporting.Level)=3)) OR (((tbl_Supporting.Level)=4));
```

Comment: Understood.

What I'm looking to do is count all the levels and 3s and 4s for each application.
But return zeros for any level 1s or 2s.

It now makes sense to me why my criteria is wrong but I'm unsure how to go about making the count only apply where the level is 3 or 4 but return zero if it's a 1 or a 2.

Comment: You can use the "smart" code I've added. Smart means that it is very specific to your values 1,2 and 3,4. Should you add, say, a level 5, it will have to be adjusted, for example using an IIf construct.